# How to align textview in right corner?

Tags: android, layout

I have the following xml .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/smsItemContainerRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:text="SMS Inbox"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/unread_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
            android:background="@drawable/notification_bg"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="88"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"    
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/SMSList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

For this , I have the following layout :

[image]

I want to shift textview of id unread_count to the right of parent . How can I do this ?

If I set  android:layout_alignParentRight="true" then I have the following picture :

[image]

I simply want to get the following picture :

[image]

Comment: You could use  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

Comment: But in that case , the right circle will fill the rest place of right

Comment: it wont fill  fill the rest place of right , it just says that the <TextView /> should be placed at the right side of the parent here(smsItemContainerRelativeLayout)

Comment: Remove   android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView" this from the attribute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add this in your `textview` of id `unread_count`

```
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

and remove this

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
```

**don't give negative margin**

add some right margin to adjust position of your `textview`

Answer (score 3):

Just set `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`

and try with this

```
android:gravity="right"
android:textAlignment="gravity"
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_alignParentRight

Answer (score 2):

Remove the following lines:

```
android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp"  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
```

and include this line

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just **Remove** this Line

```
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
```

and **add** this Line

```
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/unread_count"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
            android:background="@drawable/notification_bg"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="88"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"    
           />
```